# Receive iMessage on my lowtech phone

Tags: messages, sms

I use iMessage on my mac so now many of my friend and coworker uses it like if it was SMS.

I would like to know if there is a way to redirect my iMessage on my generic mobile device (not apple nor android)?

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna try [iMessage on Android](http://imessageonandroid.com/) which provide a nice soft

Comment: Are you certain that the app is safe to use? Most iMessage apps for Android have been harmful so far and have been pulled from Google Play Store, and it seems that this isn't available there either. Also, the site won't let you download the app without filling out your info on some ad sites.

Comment: It seems to be interesting but as @onik says I wouldn't trust this app without seeing its code source.

Comment: Anyway, android is not lowtech. Think more about something like Nokia 3310